# bootstrap star-rating plugin wrong icon

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Plugin url : http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating

I initialized the plugin using the default option, however the icon displayed seem to be overridden by something else.

[image]

Javascript

```
$("#rating").rating();
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="rating">Rating</label>
      <input type="number" data-step="1" class="form-control rating" name="rating" id="rating"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you have to include `font-awesome.min.css` also , in your page html ?

Comment: there's a `star-rating.min.css` that comes with it. And i've included that.

Comment: It is not enough as that icons are not images but fonts you have to include also `font-awesome.min.css` to your page html to make icons work

Comment: included and result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have all required resources (js, css) included as shown here in basic example for your library - https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating#user-content-usage

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="path/to/css/star-rating.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/js/star-rating.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have all of them. i suspect its a conflict with other plugins i'm using

Comment: **To debug:** you can try 1) inspect star icon with firebug and see from whot css file style applied to it 2) to close your plugins one by one and see what happens, or check which plugin uses additional fonts